# Estimating Percent Discovered

Tags: probability, missing-data, model-evaluation

### Background:

I built a model to discover potentially personal identifiable data in an image data set so that data can be anonymized.  I want to evaluate this model in terms of precision and recall so we can determine if the model's accuracy meets compliance standards.

### Problem:

Part of the reason for building the model is we had found that manual removal of this information misses some of the data that it should be removing.  Therefore my "gold standard" manual annotation frequently misses some of the personal identifiable information found by the model.  It is reasonable to review the "false positives" produced by the model to identify when it finds something the manual annotation missed, however, this does not help me find any false negatives missed by both the model and the manual annotation.  I would like to estimate the proportion of the positive data missed by both sets of annotations.

### Progress so far:

I have derived a formula for estimating proportion of the data missed as follows.  We let $P(d_{man})$ be the probability a particular positive sample is discovered by a manual annotation and $P(d_{mod})$ be the probability it is discovered by the model.  Assuming $d_{man}$ and $d_{mod}$ are independent we can calculate the probability a positive sample will be discovered by at least one of the two models as:

$P(d_{mod} \cup d_{man}) = 1-(1-P(d_{man}))(1-P(d_{mod}))$

We don't know any of the values up to this point.  However, we do know what percent of the total data discovered was found by each model.  In other words we know:

$man_{obs} = \frac{d_{mod}}{(d_{mod} \cup d_{man})}$
and $mod_{obs} = \frac{d_{man}}{(d_{mod} \cup d_{man})}$

Substituting and simplifying the above we can get an estimate of $P(d_{mod} \cup d_{man})$ in terms of our knowns as:

$P(d_{mod} \cup d_{man}) \approx \frac{man_{obs} + mod_{obs} -1}{man_{obs}mod_{obs}}$

### Questions:

1. Is there a more standard way of doing this task (approximating the fraction of the data discovered in independent samples)?
2. Is there a way to get a confidence interval on my $P(d_{mod} \cup d_{man})$ estimate.

Comment: Look at [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) and Bayes' Theorem. // Also, I think you may be confusing $P(A|B)$ with $P(A \cap B),$ so look at definition of conditional probability.

Comment: @BruceET apologies, I didn't know the latex code for union so I intended to use the "or" symbol. For some reason it didn't occur to me | indicates conditional in probability theory.